# Failed to open directory using opendir() in PHP 5.3 with 777 folder permission

Tags: php, copy, permission-denied, readdir, opendir

I am working on a PHP localhost project. I am trying to copy a folder recursively using the below function.

```
$src = '/Users/username/Desktop/test/a/b/';
$dst = '/Users/username/Desktop/test/1/2';
recurseCopy($src,$dst);
function recurseCopy($src, $dst)
{
    $dir = opendir($src);
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) {
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) {
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) {
                recurseCopy($src . '/' . $file, $dst . '/' . $file);
            } else {
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
```

**When I run this, it is triggering the warnings**

> Warning: opendir(/Users/username/Desktop/test) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Operation not permitted in /Users/username/Sites/test/index.php on line 7
>
> Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/username/Sites/test/index.php on line 9

**I have 777 permission for the folder "test" and all the sub folders**

**Is it possible to copy folders using PHP? I did move folders using the `rename` function**

Please help on this.

Comment: Try removing the last `/` from the `$src`

Comment: @Anders, Thanks for the suggestion. Tried that and not working. Still the same warnings

Comment: And you are sure that the `$src` path is correct? - I mean in relation to where your script is :) Maybe try to create a folder in the same folder as your script, and try to do the same action with that

Comment: @Anders, Thanks a lot. I was trying to execute from my local host and directory which I given was there in the Desktop. That was the issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: Good to hear! You are welcome :)